# Catching OperationVetoedException in client instead of InvalidOperationException

Tags: ravendb

I am using RavenDB UniqueConstraints bundle, when a unique constraint violates i am getting exception client side , But its InvalidOperationException , exception message explains the reason
Raven.Database.Exceptions.OperationVetoedException: PUT vetoed by Raven.Bundles.UniqueConstraints.UniqueConstraintsPutTrigger because: Ensure unique constraint

Is there anyway to catch OperationVetoedException in a try catch block

Comment: I got the answer from the creator.. https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/ravendb/cTODEveARBI